# Failed to load ISAR dylib [libisar.dylib]

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-isar

I included [isar](https://isar.dev) [on [pub.dev]](https://pub.dev/packages/isar) to my pub spec. Everything compiles for target MacOS just fine.

When I run the app and some [isar](https://pub.dev/packages/isar/install) related code gets executed, this error appears:

```
    [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] 
    Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): 
    Failed to load dynamic library '...comAPpName.../Data/libisar.dylib': 
dlopen(/...comAPpName.../Data/libisar.dylib, 0x0001): 
tried: '/...comAPpName.../Data/libisar.dylib' 
(no such file)
```

According to pub.dev, ISAR is compatible with MacOS targets.

**My fault? Or a buggy pub.dev package?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now found the solution somewhere in a [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/isar/isar/issues):

If you add [isar](https://pub.dev/packages/isar) as dependency, you need to add [isar_flutter_libs](https://pub.dev/packages/isar_flutter_libs/install) too.

Thus, you minimal pub spec.yaml need to look like so:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  isar: ^3.0.2                          
  isar_flutter_libs: ^3.0.2
```